# How an admin mute the microphone or turn off video of other participant in webRTC?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, webrtc, peer

I need an idea of how an admin access participant's camera and microphone. Also how to an admin mute the participant's microphone or turn off the video of the participant's.

Comment: Through admin client you can emit a event through signalling to participant to mute the local audio/video.